# Delay Window Trigger

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is it possible to delay a window trigger without changing window-end and window-start times?
Is the only solution developing a custom EventTimeTrigger?

I use 1 hour window period for processing different type of messages. As they trigger at the same time, I encounter a lot of resource problems. I just want to put some random delays before process() is executing, without changing the content of windows.

If I need to develop a custom EventTimeTrigger, is it possible to delay the fire , without changing the period start-end times and content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flink's time windows take an optional `WindowStagger` parameter (it's an enum) that can be used to avoid the *thundering herd* problem that arises from have all of the partitions fire their windows at the same time.

The default staggering policy is `ALIGNED`, meaning all panes fire at the same time across all partitions. The other options are `RANDOM` (hopefully obvious), and `NATURAL`, meaning the panes are staggered based on when each parallel operator received the first event.

Take a look at the docs for [`TumblingEventTimeWindows of(Time size, Time offset, WindowStagger windowStagger)`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/assigners/TumblingEventTimeWindows.html#of-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.WindowStagger-).

Comment: Hi David. I just tested WindowStagger but it seems it changes the windowStart-windowEnd time. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry; I overlooked the requirement you stated about leaving the window start, end, and contents unchanged. The staggering feature isn't going to work for you, if those are hard requirements.