# Flink, How to avoid the spikes at the end of aggregation window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink job (1.14) that computes the window aggregation every several hours. I found that all the events have the same window range so that millions of aggregation results all finish at the same time which is the end of the window.

After the aggregation, I'm supposed to immediately sink the results to external database. And this spike patterns are obviously not healthy no matter to the flink job itself or the database.

Thank you!!

I was trying to:

1. Assign the window start time differently based on user info? Cannot find anyway to do so.
2. Add some buffer inside the task chains?
   ...

Comment: Hello! Would you mind sharing some code; are you using Java or SQL? What is the time variable upon which you are basing your windows? Do you use event time, ingestion time, or processing time? Are you reading from Kafka or another system? What do you mean by task chains?

Comment: This was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75717580/2000823